# Remove react-hot-loader entirely when doing build

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

I only want hot reloading when used with a dev server. Is there anyway I can remove this entirely, even on non-production builds?

I currently have in `.babelrc`

```
"plugins": ["react-hot-loader/babel"]
```

And in `webpack.config.js`

```
entry: {
  app: [
    'babel-polyfill',
    'react-hot-loader/patch',
    './index.jsx'
  ]
},
```

I could dynamically change the `webpack.config.js` setting, but how do I do that for `babelrc`?

Answer (score 0):

You can dynamically change babel config with [.babelrc.js](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/config-files#javascript) :

> The main benefit being that users can include JS logic to build up their config structures